# I want to join 2 tables and get the data of table1 and map to table 1 entity

Tags: java, spring, jpa

[![Table 1][1]][1]

[![Table 2][2]][2]

I want to join above 2 tables with partyid and get the user data of `table1 (id, name, company, partyid)` and map to table1 entity, is it possible using JPA?

I am getting below exception when it runs

````
Failed to convert from type [java.lang.Object[]] to type [com.test.entity.table1]
nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.Long] to type [com.test.entity.table1] ```

Can anyone answer this question, please?
Thanks in advance.


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rs78C.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8zij.png
````

Comment: Can you post the query that you're running as well as your repository and entity classes?

Comment: Can you give more details about your Entitiy? and why not use FK in your table relationship?

Comment: - robertobatts
Please find the query
SELECT d.id, d.partyId, d.dunningStep, d.dunningCount, d.dunningFrequency, d.dunningPeriod, d.addedOn, d.updatedOn FROM DunningEntity d JOIN DunningPlanEntity dp ON d.partyId = dp.partyId WHERE dp.userId=?1 AND d.dunningStep=?2 order by d.id.

@MarcosEchagüe
If i will use FK when i will get table 1 data it will load table2 data, I don't want to load table2 data always when i get table1 data.

Comment: Finally i got mapped it to table1 without mapper, small change in query .
added nativeQuery = true in query and its mapped to table1, if we want table2 data also then we need to write a separate mapper to map the data. thanks for the response.
Note: when we use nativeQuery = true we have to use table name same as DB table name  in query not entity name.